# Selecting A Particular Column With The Help Of Combo Box In User Form

Tags: excel, vba

I have designed a UserForm and added a ComboBox which has range consisting of 16 different options.
How can I connect each option with a particular column? I want to select a particular column name that is same as provided in list options

I have included the options range from going into properties and then selecting row source

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
UserForm3.Show
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
UserForm3.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Typing your question in all-caps does not aid in getting a quick answer, the contrary

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to remove the ALL CAPS parts. Use of capitals like that is commonly regarded as shouting, and is likely to mean your question doesn't get the positive attention you want it to. (I'd also suggest formatting the code *as* code - see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Your code just shows the form. Can you post the form code?

Answer (score 0):

**You can benefit from `Range.Find`**

Set up an Integer

```
Dim c_num As Integer
```

Set it's value like below. It will search in the `UsedRange` for the Column Name. You can change the Name and Worksheet accordingly.

```
cnum = Worksheets("YourSheet").UsedRange.Find(ComboBox1.Text).Column
```

Will pop up the MsgBox with the Column Number

```
MsgBox "Column Selected is the " & cnum
```